# Why cannot see outline, vetex, and faces in viewpoint shading

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

I am trying t edit my object through the viewport shading. But couldn't see any vertices and faces from it. Alt+ A gives a too detailed line out. What I wanna see are only the basic outlines.

[image]

Comment: maybe disable the modifiers for the moment?

Comment: it‘s alt + z. not alt + a. sorry

Comment: The modifiers have 4 icons next to their names. Click the 2nd icon from left to disable the modifer in edit mode.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! Problem solveddddd